# How to retrieve Google Place Photos near map parker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I would like to retrieve photos from Google Place Photos that are near a clicked marker.

I already have a listener on marker click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   //
});
```

but I don't know how to proceed from here - even after reading Googles documentation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the downvote, that really helps without any comments... if you think this is an inappropriate question, you should surely know how to do it and could help...

Answer (score 0):

A Place Photo request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters
```

Required parameters

key

photoreference

maxheight or maxwidth

Comment: Yes, I've read that in the documentation. But where does the "photoreference"-parameter come from when I have a marker?

Comment: photoreference can be from Places Search `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters` 
You can get location parameter from latitude/longitude  from info window?

Comment: Sorry - but I don't see it in the JS-API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_results or is it the plain "reference"?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it could be place_id